# How is this pdf encoded? The font looks funny

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have seen this effect many times while reading pdf documents. So, some pdf have this funny smudged *font* which looks like it is a scanned image. However, I am able to select the font, and while selecting it the highlighted font appears differently as seen in the images.

Default appearance
[image: default appearance]

Appearance on selection of font
[image: highlight appearance]

Overall, seems like some ocr is happening behind the scene. 
The document reader I am using is **Atril 1.12.2** document viewer.

My question is: *What is encoded in the pdf, image or text? What is happening to text when I am selecting it?*

Comment: Please share the (URL of the) PDF in question (or an alternative PDF with the same issue). I would guess that the PDF is indeed scanned and what you see is the scanned image, but that OCR has been applied and the results have been added as text either under the image or (using the rendering mode "invisible") over it, and Atril appears to use that text information for highlighting. Furthermore, the dimensions of the text seem not to be exactly fitting. Without the PDF in question, though, this really is mere guesswork.

Comment: @mkl the document in question is [located here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097000148). Thanks for the insight. I will find another similar document and upload it here.

Comment: The pdf to buy there?

Comment: @mkl Sorry, my bad. I have located another similar pdf [file](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.4380110106/epdf)

Comment: This also looks like a PDF to buy... (I get redirected a bit from that URL, most likely because I've no account in the Wiley Online Library)

Comment: @mkl Would it be possible to share your mail id? I can mail the pdf in question. I can't share the pdf publicly.

Comment: You can use the email address you can find in [my profile here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl?tab=profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another nice change can be observed in the document shared by the OP:

[image: Unmarked]

[image: Marked]

What we see here indeed is the result of OCR. But it's not *some ocr happening behind the scene* in the viewer, OCR has already happened before and the results have been integrated into the PDF.

The PDF page actually contains a scanned image upon which invisible text is drawn.

As long as nothing is selected, Atril shows exactly that, you only see the scanned image. As soon as you start selecting text, though, it appears to cover the marked area in blue and display the marked (formerly invisible) text in white upon it.

In situations, therefore, in which the invisible text is not added exactly above the corresponding letters in the image, this might result in funny gaps like the one in the OP's screenshot after "multidimensional". In case of errors in the OCR output, one sees the erroneous data like in my screenshots.

Other PDF viewer often merely mark the text by applying some effect to the text area, e.g. inverting colors or overlaying a semi-transparent color.

It might be considered an advantage of the Atril approach that already in the selection process one sees the exact text one is selecting and probably eventually going to copy.

#### Inside the content stream

As mentioned above, the PDF page actually contains a scanned image upon which invisible text is drawn.

In the page content stream the corresponding instructions look like this:

```
1 0 0 1 0 0.2401 cm
```

(shift the coordinate system a minute bit up)

```
1 1 1 rg
1 i
/RelativeColorimetric ri
/R794 gs
0 0 576 719.5 re
f
```

(filling the image area to be with white color)

```
q
576 0 0 719.5 0 0 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
```

(drawing the bitmap image)

```
1 0 0 1 0 -0.2401 cm
```

(shift the coordinate system a minute bit down, undoing the initial upshift)

```
BT
```

(beginning a text object)

```
0 0 0 rg
```

(setting the fill color to black)

```
/TT1 1 Tf
0.05 Tc
0 Tw
3 Tr
```

(selecting the font *TT1* at size 1, a bit of extra space between characters, no extra space between words, **and text rendering mode 3, i.e. *invisible***)

```
7.3 0 0 7.3 83.8 678.4401 Tm
(SOFTWARE-PRACTICE ) Tj
```

(setting the text coordinate system to be shifted by 83.8 horizontally and 678.4401 vertically and to be scaled by 7.3 and drawing some text)

```
0.08 Tc
7.4 0 0 7.1 175.2 678.4401 Tm
(AND ) Tj
```

(changing character spacing a bit, setting the text coordinate system to be shifted by 175.2 horizontally and 678.4401 vertically and to be scaled by 7.4 horizontally and 7.1 vertically and drawing some text)

```
...
```

#### TL;DR

> What is encoded in the pdf, image or text?

Both, the image plus invisible text upon it.

> What is happening to text when I am selecting it?

Atril covers the text in blue and draws the selected (formerly invisible) text upon it in white.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The placement of the (hidden) text layer over the (scanned) image must be tedious. I wonder how such documents are created? manually or otherwise.

Comment: Many scanners and scanning applications nowadays can do OCR and automatically add the determined text information. Considering the errors in the PDF page you shared I doubt anyone manually partook in adding the text there.